# Install error: partition validation

Tags: system-installation, microsoft-windows

I'm trying to install eOS 6.0, on an external HDD. I've created the partitions correctly, but later when it is installing it, this error shows up. This is my first OS installation proccess, so I really don't know what's wrong, but after some research, it should be that my disk is MBR (?). So, now i'm converting the drive from MBR to GPT. But - is this error caused by another problem? Should I convert it anyways and try again?

P.S: I don't know if this is helpful, but for the partitions, I've managed to create one for boot, root and home (no swap), and I think they're correct because now booting from Windows using Disk Manager I can see them.

This is the error:

[image]

I'm sorry if it is something simple I'm missing, hah.

Comment: Well, actually, I did turned my disk from MBR to GPT and it worked okay. Now, I have eOS 6, so you just have to do that in case you have the same little error (:

Comment: You can answer your question and accept the answer so it will show it is closed.